# Possibly this Ibm i VIEW is creating duplicated records?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I am seeing what seems to be duplicate records from this view. Do you think this View is causing duplicate records?

```
create view astccdta.acaudia AS                      
( select d.IARCC9,b.ItQty#,a.IhDocd,b.ItPRT#        
       from astdta.OEINHDIH a                        
 join astdta.ICDETLIT     b on                      

 b.Itcom# = a.IhCom#                                
 and                                                
 b.ItTrn# = a.IhIdc#                                


 left join astdta.ICECTLCT      c on                

 c.CtCom#= b.ItCom# and                              

 c.CtCtr# = ' ' and                                  

 c.CtPrt# =b.ItPrt#                                  
left join astdta.Audia d                        
on d.IAprt# = b.ItPrt#                          

where b.ItTscc = 'I'   and  a.IHDOCD > 20120105  
and d.IARCC9 > ''                                
)
```

Comment: _"Do you think this View is causing duplicate records?"_ -- I guess you might say so, but most likely it is you who's causing duplicates -- by joining on non-unique keys.

Comment: OK good point Mustaccio i will check further.